# How do I recover or reset VMware ESXi Server root password?

Tags: password-recovery, esxi

I've inherited a VMware ESX Server 3i 3.5.0 but haven't found any documentation, especially not the root password, nor have I gotten hold of the former admin.

The suggestions I've [found](http://www.petri.co.il/vmware-esx-server-root-password-reset-recovery-lost.htm) [online](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1317898) [presuppose](http://www.vladan.fr/reset-root-password-on-esx-server/) that I first get a GRUB boot menu, which I don't.

So, lacking a GRUB menu, how do I recover or reset the root password, short of a reinstall?

If it is of any significance, the server is a Dell PowerEdge 2850.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ESX***i*** (and I'm assuming that's what you're using, based on the mentioned "3i") doesn't include the GRUB menu.

According to VMWare's ["Changing a forgotten root password on an ESX host"](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1317898) page:

> Note: This article does not pertain to ESXi. Reinstalling is the only way to reset a root password on ESXi.

Perhaps the info found at ["How to reset the root password of VMware ESXi 4.1"](http://www.bock.nu/blog/reset-root-password-vmware-esxi-4.1) will help you get into your v3 ESXi machine without a reinstall, or at least give you an idea of what you need to be looking at. :)

> According to VMware knowledge base article 1317898 it is not possible to reset the root password of an ESXi installation. Well, maybe it's not easy for non-Unix guys, but it certainly is possible.

Hope that helps...

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware that something calling itself "VMware ESX Server 3i" is in fact a "VMware ESXi Server". Apparently there was a [change in naming convention](http://virtualization.info/en/news/2008/04/vmware-renames-esx-server-in-just-esx.html) some time after the release of the software. This helps a lot, and in fact your second link seem to be my solution. I'll try that when I get back to the office.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

ESXi does not have GRUB and uses it's own bootloader. Repair installation is the only official solution supported by VMware. But it seems that some rocket scientist may have found [a way](http://vm-help.com/esx/esx3i/Reset_root_password.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the GRUB menu is hidden. This can probably be changed by editing the `menu.lst` file, but I'm pretty sure you will need root access to do that.

One thing you can try, though, is to press the `shift` key while booting. That might bring the GRUB menu up.

Comment: Alas, no cigar on the press `shift` suggestion. Thanks thou.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

how to reset vmware esxi root password

http://www.unixarena.com/2014/05/recover-vmware-esxi-root-password.html

Comment: While the link might provide the answer it can quickly become unavailable. Please can you provide the key information from the link within your answer. Thanks.